# Using external GPS project in android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location

I am using novoda (https://github.com/novoda/Novocation) external location jar in my project, I set the update interval for half a minute and I'm using the locator class in my map to show the user location, with so while trying to use the application outside, I can get my first location on the map but after that it dosent seem to "track" my location anymore - i.e. te user overlay does not relocate its position on the map accordng to the given time interval (30 seconds) - does anyone uses the same project and have an advice?
here is my code:

```
package com.mappermate.ui.phone;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.novoda.location.Locator;
import com.novoda.location.exception.NoProviderAvailable;
import com.readystatesoftware.maps.OnSingleTapListener;
    import com.readystatesoftware.maps.TapControlledMapView;
import com.mappermate.R;
import com.mappermate.application.MappermateApp;
import com.mappermate.logic.config.MappermateConfig;
import com.mappermate.logic.gps.GPSTracker;
import com.mappermate.logic.mapmenu.MapSearchMenu;
import com.mappermate.logic.mapoverlays.CustomItemizedOverlay;
import com.mappermate.logic.mapoverlays.CustomOverlayItem;
import com.mappermate.logic.mapoverlays.SimpleItemizedOverlay;
import com.mappermate.logic.mapoverlays.UserItemizedOverlay;
import com.mappermate.logic.mapoverlays.UserOverlayItem;
import com.mappermate.logic.net.AlertDialogManager;
import com.mappermate.logic.net.ConnectionDetector;

public class MyLocationActivity extends MapActivity implements LocationListener{

private TapControlledMapView m_MapView; // use the custom
                                        //     TapControlledMapView
private List<Overlay> m_MapOverlays;
Drawable redCircle;
Drawable greenCircle;
CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem> itemizedOverlayWithPicture;
SimpleItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlayWithoutPicture;
/**
 * Added after original
 */
// Checkers to validate user have an open network connection
// And an active GPS
private ConnectionDetector m_ConnectionDetector;
private AlertDialogManager m_Alert = new AlertDialogManager();

// User overlay
private double m_UserLongitude;
private double m_UserLatitude;
private Drawable m_UserLocationMarker;
private GeoPoint m_UserGeoPoint;
private UserOverlayItem m_UserOverlayItem;
private UserItemizedOverlay m_UserItemizedOverlay;

// Class variables
private static ImageButton m_MapMenuButton;
private GPSTracker m_GPS;
private boolean m_WorkOffline;
private final static int ZOOM_LEVEL = 17;
private MapController m_MapController;
private static final int USER_OVERLAY = 0;
private static final int PLACES_OVERLAY = 1;
private MapSearchMenu m_MapSerachMenu;
private final int TRANSPERENT = 150;
private final int OPAQUE = 255;
private View m_View;
// Added those for locator jar file
Locator m_Locator;
MappermateApp m_MappermateApp;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the map with the given xml and return to saved instance in
    // Case there is such one
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);


    // Get the reference to the locator object
    m_MappermateApp = (MappermateApp) getApplication();
    m_Locator = m_MappermateApp.getLocator();

    // Initiate class fields
    InitiateMapFields();

    // Get the map and set the zoom controls to on
    m_MapView = (TapControlledMapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    m_MapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);

    // Get the map overlays - to place objects on
    m_MapOverlays = m_MapView.getOverlays();

    // Place user on map
    initUserLocationOnMap();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        m_MapController = m_MapView.getController();
        m_MapController.setZoom(ZOOM_LEVEL);
        if (m_UserGeoPoint != null) {
            m_MapController.animateTo(m_UserGeoPoint);
        }
    } else {
        // restoring focused state of overlays
        int focused;
        focused = savedInstanceState.getInt("focused_1", -1);
        if (focused >= 0) {
            itemizedOverlayWithPicture.setFocus(itemizedOverlayWithPicture
                    .getItem(focused));
        }
        focused = savedInstanceState.getInt("focused_2", -1);
        if (focused >= 0) {
            itemizedOverlayWithoutPicture
                    .setFocus(itemizedOverlayWithoutPicture
                            .getItem(focused));
        }
    }
}

/***********************************************************
 *********************************************************** 
 **************** Initiate Class Members *******************
 *********************************************************** 
 ***********************************************************/
private void InitiateMapFields() {
    // Init the classes
    m_ConnectionDetector = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
    m_GPS = new GPSTracker(MyLocationActivity.this);

    // Set the map buttons images their listeners
    m_MapMenuButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.show_map_menu);
    m_MapMenuButton.setAlpha(TRANSPERENT);
}

/*******************************************
 ****************************************** 
 ******** User overlay methods ************
 ****************************************** 
 ******************************************/

private void initUserLocationOnMap() {
    // User overlay on map
    m_UserLocationMarker = getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.user_location);
    m_UserItemizedOverlay = new UserItemizedOverlay(m_UserLocationMarker,
            m_MapView);

    // set OS behavior attributes for overlay
    m_UserItemizedOverlay.setShowClose(true);
    // m_UserItemizedOverlay.setShowDisclosure(true);
    m_UserItemizedOverlay.setSnapToCenter(true);
}

/**
 * Add the current user location to the map
 * 
 * @param i_GeoPoint
 *            - The user current location
 */
public void addUserLocationAndInvalidate(GeoPoint i_GeoPoint) {
    m_MapOverlays = m_MapView.getOverlays();
    if (m_MapOverlays.contains(m_UserItemizedOverlay)) {
        m_MapOverlays.remove(m_UserItemizedOverlay);
    }
    m_UserOverlayItem = new UserOverlayItem(i_GeoPoint);
    m_UserItemizedOverlay.addOverlay(m_UserOverlayItem);
    m_MapOverlays.add(m_UserItemizedOverlay);
    m_MapView.invalidate();
    m_MapController.animateTo(i_GeoPoint);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    .show();
}

/************************************************************************
 ************ Default inherited methods and menu methods ****************
 ************************************************************************/

// Saving state of overlays
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle i_OutState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(i_OutState);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(MappermateApp.LOCATION_UPDATE_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(m_FreshLocationReceiver, intentFilter);
    try {
        m_Locator.startLocationUpdates();
    } catch (NoProviderAvailable i_NoProviderAvailable) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No provider available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        m_UserGeoPoint = getLastKnownLocation();
    }
}

private GeoPoint getLastKnownLocation() {
    GeoPoint geopoint = null;
    Location location;
    long bestTime = -1;
    boolean hasResult = false;
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    List<String> providers = locationManager.getAllProviders();
    if (providers != null) {
        for (String provider : providers) {
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if (location != null) {
                hasResult = true;
                if (location.getTime() > bestTime) {
                    geopoint = new GeoPoint(
                            (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                            (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));
                    bestTime = location.getTime();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (hasResult)
        return geopoint;
    return null;
}

public BroadcastReceiver m_FreshLocationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        m_UserLatitude = m_Locator.getLocation().getLatitude();
        m_UserLongitude = m_Locator.getLocation().getLongitude();
        m_UserGeoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (m_UserLatitude * 1E6),
                (int) (m_UserLongitude * 1E6));
        addUserLocationAndInvalidate(m_UserGeoPoint);
    }
};

@Override
public void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(m_FreshLocationReceiver);
    m_Locator.stopLocationUpdates();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    addUserLocationAndInvalidate(new GeoPoint(
            (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
            (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6)));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}
```

Comment: can you add `debug` message in `onLocationChanged` to see if your receive location updates correctly?

Comment: I can, problem is that by the documentation i dont need the location listener interface since the jar on the github project i mentioned suppose to tkae care of that, since the broadcast reciever suppose to be registred for the gps/network updates.... I added the locationlistener only as a frustrated step... =\